# Linear Algebra: Proving Linear Independence In A Generated Set Of Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I apologize for the title, the question statement was just rather lengthy and I failed to summarize it effectively.

Problem: Let $V$ be a vector space over a field F, and let $\{{u_1,…,u_n\}}$ be a basis for $V$. Let $v_1,…,v_k$ Be vectors in $V$, and suppose $$v_j=\sum^{n}_{k=1}{\alpha_{k,j}u_k},\quad j=1,2,…,k.$$
Define the vector $x_1,…,x_k$ In $F^n$ by $$x_j=\left(\alpha_{1,j},…,\alpha_{n,j}\right),\quad j=1,2,…,k.$$
Show that $v_1,…,v_k$ Is linearly independent if and only if $x_1,…,x_k$ Is linearly independent.

Attempt: Logically, I would want to make a connection between the elements of any given vector $u$ and the scalar multipliers $\alpha$, but I have yet to either learn of such a concept or have the understanding to utilize a concept I do know in such a way. Otherwise, I would intuitively want to claim this question to be unprovable, but obviously that cannot be the case if I am asked to prove and not disprove. I used a $2\times 2$ numerical example and could not find why the logic carries through.

As always with the questions I pose, I truly appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 1):

The statement
$$v_j=\sum^{n}_{k=1}{\alpha_{k,j}u_k},\quad j=1,2,…,k$$
says that the coordinate column vector of $v_j$, with respect to the basis $B = (u_1, \ldots, u_n)$, is
$$[v_j]_B = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha_{1,j} \\ \vdots \\ \alpha_{n, j}\end{bmatrix}.$$
So, the question boils down to, prove that $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ is linearly independent if and only if $([v_1]_B, \ldots, [v_n]_B)$ (which is essentially $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ written as columns rather than rows) is linearly independent.

Hopefully this observation is sufficient to convince you that this is actually true! The map $v \mapsto [v]_B$ is an isometry from a space $V$ of dimension $n$ over a field $\Bbb{F}$ to $\Bbb{F}^n$; these are important maps to show that finite-dimensional vector spaces are really just $\Bbb{F}^n$ in disguise. So, we should expect linear independence (and similarly spanning) to carry over without much fuss! Indeed, everything I've mentioned above is completely standard, so if you've covered these results previously in your course, you could give a one-line proof just citing the above results. But, we can also workshop a self-contained proof.

Look at the abstracted version. Suppose $T$ is an isomorphism between spaces $V$ and $W$. Then $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ is linearly independent if and only if $(Tv_1, \ldots, Tv_n)$ is. This is shown by showing that
$$\beta_1 v_1 + \ldots + \beta_n v_n = 0_V \iff \beta_1 Tv_1 + \ldots + \beta_n Tv_n = 0_W.$$
This is straightforward to show using the linearity and injectivity of $T$ (actually, surjectivity is not necessary, and would be used in the dual spanning problem). Let's try showing this correspondence directly in our specific case, i.e.
$$\beta_1 v_1 + \ldots + \beta_n v_n = 0 \iff \beta_1 x_1 + \ldots + \beta_n x_n = 0. \tag{$\star$}$$
This is clearly sufficient to finish the problem. If $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ is linearly independent, then the left side is equivalent to $\beta_1 = \ldots = \beta_n = 0$, and hence so is the right. Similarly, if $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is linearly independent, then the right side is equivalent to $\beta_1 = \ldots = \beta_n = 0$, and hence so is the left. So, all we need to do is prove $(\star)$.

Suppose that $\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_n$ are scalars. Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^n \beta_j v_j = 0 &\iff \sum_{j=1}^n \beta_j \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_{k, j} u_k \\
&\iff \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\sum_{j=1}^n \beta_j \alpha_{k, j}\right) u_k \\
&\iff \sum_{j=1}^n \beta_j \alpha_{k, j} = 0, \quad \forall k = 1, \ldots, n \\
&\iff \left(\sum_{j=1}^n \beta_j \alpha_{1, j}, \ldots, \sum_{j=1}^n \beta_j \alpha_{n, j}\right) = 0 \\
&\iff \sum_{j=1}^n \beta_j \left(\alpha_{1, j}, \ldots, \alpha_{n, j}\right) = 0 \\
&\iff \sum_{j=1}^n \beta_j x_j = 0,
\end{align*}
where the third equivalence follows from the $u_k$s being linearly independent.

Comment: The classic "take a break if you're stuck". This seems a lot more obvious now. Thanks for your time!